# Polymer custom-row-style in paper-datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, styles, polymer, row

I try set custom-row-style in paper-datatable. [demo](http://david-mulder.github.io/paper-datatable/components/paper-datatable/demo/miscellaneous/theming.html)

This is working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-datatable/paper-datatable.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
            <paper-datatable data="{{data}}"  custom-row-style="{{generateRowCss}}" >
                <paper-datatable-column header="Calories" property="calories"></paper-datatable-column>
            </paper-datatable>
        </template>     
        <script>
            var app = document.querySelector('#app');
            app.data = [
                {id: 0, title: 'Frozen yogurt', calories: 159},
                {id: 0, title: 'Frozen yogurt', calories: 159}
            ];
            app.generateRowCss = function(item){
                return 'background:red;';
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

generateRowCss is a property, not a function

If I try insert in my module:

```
var app2 = document.querySelector('#idModule');
or var app2 = document.getElementById('idModule');
app2.generateRowCss = function(item){return 'background:red;';};
```

app2 return null

Best way for me - to use the properties of the polymer:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'idModule',
    properties: {
      generateRowCss: {
        type: String,
        value: "background:red;"
or function(item){return 'background:red;';}
or computed: '_generateRowCss(item)'  
      },
```

However, this causes errors in the polymer modules:
Uncaught TypeError: this.customRowStyle is not a function.

Comment: Answer is here: 
[polymer-paper-datatable-styling-of-rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927817/polymer-paper-datatable-styling-of-rows?noredirect=1#comment63309570_37927817)