# Polymer, paper-datatable styling of rows

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, styling

I'm trying to colour the rows of paper-datatable
using the attribute [customRowStyle](http://david-mulder.github.io/paper-datatable/components/paper-datatable/docs/api.html?datatable#customRowStyle)

This [Plunk of paper-datatable](http://plnkr.co/edit/wNewjFnTEjEACwzAvwSd?p=preview) is working, rows are colored, but it's not enclosed as separate Polymer element.

I need to enclose  paper-datatable in separate element.

Need some help to fix this:
how to make `customRowStyle(item)` to get called on table render and pass the `item`?

```
 <paper-datatable data="{{data}}" 
                         custom-row-style="{{generateRowCss}}"
                         on-row-tap="row_tap">

            <paper-datatable-column header="title" property="title"></paper-datatable-column>
            <paper-datatable-column header="Calories" property="calories"></paper-datatable-column>
            <paper-datatable-column header="Fat (g)" property="fat" ></paper-datatable-column>

</paper-datatable>

...

generateRowCss: function (item) {
                console.log('theming_2 generateRowCss:');
                var levels = ['#FFFFFF', '#FFEBEE', '#FFCDD2', '#EF9A9A'];
                var min = 150;
                var max = 450;
                var level = Math.floor((item.calories - min) / (max - min) * levels.length);
                return 'background:' + levels[level] + ';';
},
```

EDIT:
  [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4B2H0whGXROcvXnbx9y?p=preview) with @a1626 solution.

Comment: Have you tried setting the style function in one of the callbacks (for example, in `ready`)?

Comment: From what i understand what your code and working code are doing are completely different things. You are assigning a single value to `customRowStyle` whereas in original plunkr whole function has been assigned to same. You can declare your function outside the Polymer constructor like normal js and it should work. Also you can try [this](http://david-mulder.github.io/paper-datatable/components/paper-datatable/docs/docs.html?styling). This is more like per column styling

Comment: @a1626 , at working example customRowStyle gets called on rendering each row, in my app that is not happening. First, How to replicate that inside Polymer element? And then question is what data should be passed in customRowStyle(data). 
(p.s. link you posted is for header and cells styling, not for the rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `generateRowCss`that is passed to `customRowStyle` is a function rather than the return value of the function(which is what your code is passing) you'll have to do something like this. Instead of creating a function `generateRowCss` create a property with the same name, initialize it as Object and return its value as whole function

```
properties: {
            data: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true,
                value: [
                    {id: 0, title: 'Frozen yogurt', calories: 159, fat: 6},
                    {id: 1, title: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: 237, fat: 9},
                    {id: 2, title: 'Eclair', calories: 262, fat: 16},
                    {id: 3, title: 'Cupcake', calories: 305, fat: 3.7},
                ],
    },
    generateRowCss:{
      type:Object, //this is optional you can skip this also
      value:function(){
        return function(item){
                        console.log('app.generateRowCss');
                        console.log(item);
            var levels = ['#FFFFFF', '#FFEBEE', '#FFCDD2', '#EF9A9A'];
            var min = 150;
            var max = 450;
            var level = Math.floor((item.calories - min)/(max-min)*levels.length);
                        console.log(level);
                        console.log('background:'+levels[level]+';');
            return 'background:'+levels[level]+';';
        }  
      }

    }
  },
```

Pasted above are the `properties` of  your custom element. Here is the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/35FF8rdnQICaLYSgaAyY?p=preview)

Comment: returning function was even new for me. Give me some time i'll update my answer i think it can be achieved in one more way and i'm still not sure if `type:Object` is required here.